# 14.10 simply will not load

Tags: 14.04

When using 14.04 I was suddenly unable to get to the software center; got error messages saying something was wrong with apt-get, I think. I "upgraded" to 14.10 and the situation remained unchanged. Indeed, now I can no longer back up to Dropbox because I cannot reinstall their app. Things only got worse. Now I only get a black screen which alternates between a series of text lines and, if I hit an arrow key, a legend "ubuntu 14/10" which just stays there. Naturally, I'm writing this from my (ugh) Windows partition. but I'm getting so damn fed up with ubuntu (free and worth every penny?) that I might have to buy a Mac. Can somebody help getting me up and running? Bonus: If you' re in Miami, come here and I'll buy lunch.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden folder for dropbox you can remove that and it will have to reinstall is' self

If you are stuck at the boot enter recovery mode(go to the recovery option in grub) and if this does not work there is not much you can do